# Entity Framework adding too many records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

**EDIT: See the bottom of this question for the working code.**

I have two tables, Patients and Drugs, that I am updating with a data feed. I get a current list of patients, then iterate through and update or insert records as appropriate. This works without issue.

The trouble comes when I iterate through that patient's current medications. I end up getting multiple copies of the original patient. Drug records are transferred as expected (the records themselves don't change so new records are inserted and existing records ignored). I end up with the original patient record (inserted from UpdatePatients() below) and then one additional patient record for each medication record. Each medication record ends up with a distinct PatientId.

Class definitions:

```
public class Patient
{
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FacilityNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PatNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime VentStart { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime VentEnd { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime AdmitDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DischargeDate { get; set; }
}

public class Drug
{
    public int DrugId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int DrugDDI { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DrugName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DispenseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double UnitsDispensed { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Patient")]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

Offending code:

```
private static void UpdatePatients()
{
    var Patients = DB2Patient.GetPatients();

    foreach (Patient p in Patients)
    {
        using (var PatientContext = new VAEContext())
        {
            var ExistingPatientRecord = PatientContext.Patients.FirstOrDefault(
                ep => ep.PatNo == p.PatNo
            );
            if (ExistingPatientRecord != null)
            {
                ExistingPatientRecord.VentEnd = p.VentEnd;
                ExistingPatientRecord.DischargeDate = p.DischargeDate;
                PatientContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                PatientContext.Patients.Add(p);
                PatientContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        UpdateDrugs(p);
    }
}

private static void UpdateDrugs(Patient p)
{
    var Drugs = DB2Drug.GetDrugs(p.PatNo);
    foreach (Drug d in Drugs)
    {
        using (var DrugContext = new VAEContext())
        {
            var ExistingDrugRecord = DrugContext.Drugs.FirstOrDefault(
                ed => ed.DrugDDI == d.DrugDDI &&
                      ed.DispenseDate == d.DispenseDate &&
                      ed.OrderId == d.OrderId
            );
            if (ExistingDrugRecord == null)
            {
                d.Patient = p;
                DrugContext.Drugs.Add(d);
                DrugContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Working code:**

```
private static void UpdatePatients()
{
    var Patients = DB2Patient.GetPatients();

    using (var db = new VAEContext())
    {
        foreach (Patient p in Patients)
        {
            var ExistingPatientRecord = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(
                ep => ep.PatNo == p.PatNo
            );
            if (ExistingPatientRecord != null)
            {
                ExistingPatientRecord.VentEnd = p.VentEnd;
                ExistingPatientRecord.DischargeDate = p.DischargeDate;
            }
            else
            {
                db.Patients.Add(p);
            }
            UpdateDrugs(p, db);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

private static void UpdateDrugs(Patient p, VAEContext ctx)
{
    var Drugs = DB2Drug.GetDrugs(p.PatNo);
    foreach (Drug d in Drugs)
    {
        var ExistingDrugRecord = ctx.Drugs.FirstOrDefault(
            ed => ed.DrugDDI == d.DrugDDI &&
                  ed.DispenseDate == d.DispenseDate &&
                  ed.OrderId == d.OrderId
        );
        if (ExistingDrugRecord == null)
        {
            d.Patient = p;
            ctx.Drugs.Add(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why new context every time something needs to be inserted? Both methods `UpdatePatients` and `UpdateDrugs` are private, you can use the same context for all linked operations and I'm sure you won't get the duplicates:

```
private static void UpdateDrugs(Patient p, VAEContext context)
```

...

Also there's probably no need to save on every drug, doing so likely decreases performance and doesn't do much in terms of data integrity. Consider saving the context changes once per linked updates (say after UpdateDrugs is called in UpdatePatients)

Other than that you can check out the ObjectContext.Attach and related methods on how to link the Patient object to your newly created Drugs context instance

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx

Comment: I am still learning EF and the best practices associated with it. This does exactly what I need, I hadn't though to do this. I will update my question to contain the working code for future reference. Thanks!